# CSS- How to change images shape from circular to squared or star?

Tags: html, css, image, geometry, css-shapes

I have the follow CSS to make images circular but Is it possible to make them star shaped or square shaped?

```
/* Effect 12: circle */
.cl-effect-12 a::before,
.cl-effect-12 a::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: '';
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(0.2);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(0.2);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(0.2);
}
```

Comment: See this resource: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: This might help: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

Answer (score 1):

With "it makes my images circular" I assume you mean that it shows a round 'cut-out' of the image. With that in mind, I think what you want is called [CSS Masking](http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking). All of the following is taking from that source, but provided here in the answer in case of link rot.

> CSS masks were added to the WebKit engine by Apple quite a while ago,
>   namely back in April 2008. Masks offer the ability to control the
>   opacity/transparency of elements on a per-pixel basis, similar to how
>   the alpha/transparency-channel of "24-bit"-PNGs or 32-bit-TIFFs work.

### Emulating a simple -webkit-mask-image cross browser

So let's say we want to mask an HTML element to the shape of a mouse's head as seen in the picture on the right.

With **WebKit's proprietary** CSS masks we would have this HTML:

```
<div class="element">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit … amet.</p>
</div>
```

And define the following CSS:

```
.element {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    background: url(background.png);
    -webkit-mask-image: url(mouse.png);
}
```

### The modern browsers

[...] Next step is to define an SVG-mask inside our inlined SVG that we can feed a mask image, and then apply that via style="mask:[mask id]" to our foreignObject/embedded HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <!-- SVG begins -->
    <svg>

        <!-- Definition of a mask begins -->
        <defs>
            <mask id="mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <image width="400px" height="300px" xlink:href="mouse.png"></image>
            </mask>
        </defs>
        <!-- Definition of a mask ends -->

        <foreignObject width="400px" height="300px" style="mask: url(#mask);">

            <!-- HTML begins -->
            <div class="element">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit … amet.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- HTML ends -->

        </foreignObject>
    </svg>
    <!-- SVG ends -->

</body>
</html>
```

And finally we need to have a proper mask image. We cannot simply use the image from WebKit's proprietary CSS mask, since SVG masks do not look at transparency values but at luminance values. So what we need to do is turn all opaque image pixels into shades of white.

In Photoshop that's super easy:

- Open the transparent 24-bit-PNG you want to use as mask
- Select the "Layer" menu, then "Layer Style" and finally "Color Overlay"
- In the "Color Overlay" dialog change the color to white
- Close the dialog with "OK"
- Select the "File" menu, "Save for web", and replace the old file.

And KABOOOM! Masking of HTML content is up and running in WebKit, Firefox and Opera! Nice.

[image: White mouse mask]

Would then create a mask for any element under it:

[image: Mouse masked element]

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `border-radius: 50%` then they will be square